# Custom UIPanGestureRecognizer to begin based on touch begin position?

Tags: ios, swift

How would you make a UIPanGestureRecognizer only begin the gesture if lets say the user starts touching a certain area of the screen.

Let's say, we want to allow the gesture only if the user starts touching from the upper 20% of the screen.

I looked into gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, but found no way of knowing where the touch begin position is.

Comment: I found myself... somehow I missed this for quite a while.
This works:

if (gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view).y <= (gestureRecognizer.view?.frame.size.height)! * 0.2)
        {
            return true
        }

Comment: if you found the solution, post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself... somehow I missed this for quite a while.
This works:

```
if (gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view).y <= (gestureRecognizer.view?.frame.size.height)! * 0.2) { return true }
```